# Process working set vs. committed memory

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx) article says:

> Processes in Windows NT have a minimal set of pages called a working
>   set that, in order for the process to run properly, must be present in
>   memory when running.

But that implies that it's somehow different from committed memory. How is that possible? Does that mean that some of the committed memory isn't really necessary for the process to run?

Comment: The rest of the process's memory can be on disk and paged in when needed.

Comment: It isn't phrased very clearly.  What it really means (I think) is that certain pages, because they are used frequently, must be kept in memory if the process is to perform adequately.  Any process *could* in principle run with only one or two pages loaded at a time (the page(s) being referenced by the particular machine code instruction being executed) but it would run very ... very ... slowly.